# How to generate .tez file to import into Temple wallet

Tags: tezos-client, temple, encrypt

I had to blow away the Temple wallet extension on Chrome then reinstall. I know I'll have to reload my mainnet wallet with the seed phrase, but I was trying to reload the wallet for my ghostnet account. The account address and keys were generated on the server using the octez client over a year ago.

Options to import the wallet into Temple is with a seed phrase, which I don't think I have since I'm using a hot key on ghostnet, or with a .tez keystore file.  I was able to generate an encrypted key from the hot unencrypted key, but I don't know what format the .tez file needs to be. I tried a plain file with just the encrypted key in it and nothing else (not json) but Temple says not the correct format. [This](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3994/keystore-file-format-for-kukai-and-other-wallets) is the closest I could come to some information regarding a keystore format, but no idea how to generate that.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I "rediscovered" the import account options from the Temple profile icon on the top right. This time, I had more options for importing the existing account, including simply entering the encrypted key I had saved.  We're good now.